# Slow boot on newly installed Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS

Tags: boot

I have installed Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS newly on my system. But, the boot time is too long.

`systemd-analyze blame` output:

```
systemd-analyze blame
     35.473s plymouth-quit-wait.service
     29.139s dev-sda1.device
     25.907s gpu-manager.service
     23.627s systemd-journal-flush.service
     19.170s console-setup.service
     15.164s apparmor.service
     13.566s snap-gnome\x2d3\x2d26\x2d1604-74.mount
     12.866s snap-gnome\x2dsystem\x2dmonitor-57.mount
     11.583s snap-gnome\x2dlogs-45.mount
     10.989s dns-clean.service
      7.088s NetworkManager-wait-online.service
      4.690s snapd.service
      4.595s systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service
      4.298s accounts-daemon.service
      4.238s NetworkManager.service
      3.946s networking.service
      3.321s dev-loop7.device
      3.289s bolt.service
      3.215s udisks2.service
      3.123s dev-loop5.device
      3.079s systemd-resolved.service
      3.062s networkd-dispatcher.service
      3.041s dev-loop6.device
```

`systemd-analyze critical-chain` output:

```
The time after the unit is active or started is printed after the "@" character.
The time the unit takes to start is printed after the "+" character.

graphical.target @1min 10.729s
└─multi-user.target @1min 10.729s
  └─kerneloops.service @42.318s +98ms
    └─network-online.target @42.267s
      └─NetworkManager-wait-online.service @35.178s +7.088s
        └─NetworkManager.service @30.934s +4.238s
          └─dbus.service @29.177s
            └─basic.target @29.166s
              └─sockets.target @29.166s
                └─snapd.socket @29.082s +83ms
                  └─sysinit.target @28.975s
                    └─systemd-backlight@backlight:intel_backlight.service @54.82
                      └─system-systemd\x2dbacklight.slice @54.820s
                        └─system.slice @2.404s
                          └─-.slice @2.376s
```

How to fix my booting time problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to disable snap, gpu-manager.service. These services take much time. If you can determine which service is the bad guy, you can work on that particular service and find a reason why.

Comment: Thanks! I disabled both. Is the 'plymouth-quit-wait.service' necessary during boot? If not, how to disable it?